# Do meta refresh tags "break" PHP sessions?

Tags: php, html

I am using session variables to store user display settings while their session is active.

For example, if I choose to display 5 items on the page with session variables then there is no problem. I can manually (f5) refresh the page and still see 5 items on the page. However, upon implementing the following meta tag to auto-refresh, every time the page refreshes it switches to the default value of 3.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

I expect maybe this meta refresh is causing a new session to be created and therefore the user setting is simply out of the picture.

Does anyone have experience with this type of issue - is this the case and is there a known way to implement a page refresh and still maintain session?

Comment: What browser are you testing with?

Comment: I hadn't considered testing with another browser, but, Firefox.

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my own experience, nope, it doesn't and it shouldn't. Unless of course you refresh it after the session timeout.

Is javascript `setTimeout` and `replace` an alternative yuou are considering?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.setTimeout('location.replace(location.href)', 300 * 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: I found the problem. Your comment prompted me to implement a few more isset statements to confirm the status of the session. I found that the variable used to maintain sessions was not being stored correctly, therefore making the session more or less useless.

Thanks for the course correction! I also implemented the Javascript just in case.

Comment: Haha, ok. I don't think I meant my answer that way. Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending it from PHP itself using `header()`.

```
header("Refresh: 300");
```